# Get better performance in a 2d voxel world using normal javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

I'm trying to render a big voxel world on a 2d plane. I'm using the 2d canvas renderer with https://www.infinite-canvas.org/ to render all the tiles. But as expected, when I render the world that is around (100000 x 100000) with diffrent colors i get low frames/crash. How can I instance the 2d voxels/ get better performance? Or is this simply not possible in a normal canvas, in that case what's the best alternative for doing this.

```
//demo code
 
// import https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emilefokkema/infinite-canvas@v0.3-alpha/dist/infinite-canvas.js
 
var canvasElement = document.getElementById("canvas");
var rect = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect();
canvasElement.width = rect.width;
canvasElement.height = rect.height;
var canvas = new InfiniteCanvas(canvasElement);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { alpha: false });
 
function create_block(position, color){
    ctx.fillStyle = color
}
 
for (var x = 0; x < 10000; x++){
    for (var z = 0; z < 10000; z++){
        create_block({x: x,z: z}, '#thecolor')
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `create_block` do?

Comment: create_block runs ctx.fillRect(position.x,position.z, 100, 100)

Comment: Then you can greatly improve perfs by drawing a single rect that covers all this area since apparently all these rects do overlap. And if they don't overlap, then build the path with `rect()` and call `fill()` only once. Anyway, please provide an [mcve].

Comment: Yes, the example i provided in the question reproduces what im trying to do. I just want to be able to add large amounts of 2D voxels into the canvas with diffrent colors using the create_block function.

Comment: No this doesn't reproduce the error here you are just setting the fillstyle, not drawing anything.

Comment: Just add ctx.fillRect(position.x,position.z, 100, 100) in the create_block function.
Under fill Color.

Comment: I mean, it's your question, you have to do it.